# Regexp cut end of string

Tags: php, regex

I have a text:

```
<p>Stackoverflow is the best</p>site
```

and I would like to get only

```
Stackoverflow is the best
```

I combine with:

```
/<p>[\s\S]+</p>/
```

but I get `Stackoverflow is the best site`.

`[\s\S]+` <= it must be, because between `<p>` and `</p>` can be everything

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: **[this](https://regex101.com/r/aD9lP4/2)**..and yes, don't forget to use parser while parsing `HTML`

Comment: Make it lazy: [`<p>([\s\S]+?)</p>`](https://regex101.com/r/aZ6nD7/1)

Comment: @Jan be careful, OP is using regex in `//`

Comment: @rock321987: I changed the delimiters in my demo to `~`.

Comment: I have this and it not works: https://regex101.com/r/aD9lP4/3

Comment: do you need a regex for only that particular string or there can be more complex cases(with nested `<p>` elements) ?

Comment: I want to get only text between <p> and </p> in <div class="text"> and i want to get data-vc="0", where 0 isn't const

Answer (score -2):

Can you show the PHP code ?  I think the regular expression should be:

```
<p>[\s\S]+<\/p>
```